# Why does this function produce chaotic results instead of calculating Conway's Game Of Life?

Tags: arrays, ruby, boolean, conways-game-of-life

I am writing Conway's Game Of Life in Ruby. The game is based on a 2d array of booleans where true represents an alive cell and false represents a dead cell. (e. g.

```
arr = [
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, true, false,  false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, true,  false, false],
    [false, false, true,  true,  true,  false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
]
```

would be for making  a glider)
According to the rules, as I'm sure most of you know, it should create a pattern that repeatedly reforms to the right and bottom. However, when I run this code, it produces a chaotic pattern that explodes. [image: Gif with the chaotic result.]
Here's my main function, which calculates the new board state:

```rb
def iterate(arr) 
  arr = arr.dup
  new_arr = arr
  y_counter = 0
  arr.each do |elem|
    x_counter = 0
    elem.each do 
      count = 0
      neighbors = [
        (arr[y_counter-1] || [false, false, false])[x_counter-1], 
        (arr[y_counter-1] || [false, false, false])[x_counter], 
        (arr[y_counter-1]|| [false, false, false])[x_counter+1],
        (arr[y_counter]|| [false, false, false])[x_counter-1],
        (arr[y_counter]|| [false, false, false])[x_counter+1],
        (arr[y_counter+1]|| [false, false, false])[x_counter-1],
        (arr[y_counter+1]|| [false, false, false])[x_counter],
        (arr[y_counter+1]|| [false, false, false])[x_counter+1],
      ]
      neighbors.each do |elem|
        count += 1 if elem
      end
      new_arr[y_counter][x_counter] = (count == 2) || (count == 3 && arr[y_counter][x_counter])
      x_counter+=1
  
    end
    
    y_counter+=1
  end
  new_arr
end
```

Why doesn't it work, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: This game of life is deterministic right? Might be worth cross-checking your results with someone else's existing implementation ...

Comment: I have checked the results. This should form the glider pattern

Comment: Which will reform to the bottom and left

Comment: I haven't studied your code thoroughly but have you dealt with cases where, for an array `arr`, `x_counter-1 #=> -1` and `x_counter+1 #=> arr.size`, as `arr[-1]` is the same as `arr[arr.size-1]` and `arr[arr.size] #=> nil`? Also, are you updating all cells simultaneously at each iteration (as per the GoL rules).

Comment: Umm ... `new_arr = arr.dup` ? You're duping, then linking, so you'd expect the array to mutate while you're working on it?

Comment: I don't want to mutate the array. The function is (somewhat) side effect free, so it returns a value instead of mutating the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing your code with a few methods to perform different tasks. Firstly, we will need to display a picture of the grid in a terminal. We might do that as follows.

```
ALIVE = "" 
DEAD = ""
```

```
def display_grid(grid)
  last_col = grid.first.size
  system("clear")
  grid.each_index do |i|
    puts (0..last_col).map { |j| grid[i][j] ? ALIVE : DEAD }.join
  end
end
```

```
display_grid(grid)
```

`system("clear")` clears the terminal in OS X and Linux. `system("cls")` does the same in Windows. I understand Ruby v2.7 has introduced a cross-platform way to do that:

```
require 'io/console'
$stdout.clear_screen # or STDOUT.clear_screen
```

---

Next, for each cell in the grid we will need to count the number of its immediate neighbors who are alive.

```
def neighbors_alive(grid, (row, col))
   rows = ([row-1, 0].max..[row+1, arr.size-1].min).to_a
   cols = ([col-1, 0].max..[col+1, arr.first.size-1].min).to_a
   neighbors = rows.product(cols) - [cell]
   neighbors.count { |row, col| grid[row][col] }
end
```

For example:

```
neighbors_alive(grid, [0, 0])  #=> 0 
neighbors_alive(grid, [1, 1])  #=> 0
neighbors_alive(grid, [2, 2])  #=> 1
neighbors_alive(grid, [3, 3])  #=> 5
neighbors_alive(grid, [4, 4])  #=> 2
neighbors_alive(grid, [5, 5])  #=> 1
neighbors_alive(grid, [6, 6])  #=> 0
```

The calculations are as follows for the cell `[4, 3]`, which is centered in the following 3x3 subarray:

```
[false, false, true],  #  
[true,  true,  true],  # 
[false, false, false]] #
```

so we expect that number to be `3`.

```
row, col = [4, 3]
row
  #=> 4 
col
  #=> 3 
rows = ([row-1, 0].max..[row+1, arr.size-1].min).to_a
  #=> [3, 4, 5] 
cols = ([col-1, 0].max..[col+1, arr.first.size-1].min).to_a
  #=> [2, 3, 4] 
neighbors = rows.product(cols) - [[row, col]]
  #=> [[3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 2], [4, 4], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4]]
  #                                                  
neighbors.count { |row, col| grid[row][col] }
  #=> 3
```

---

At each iteration we need to construct an array of live cells that will die (`to_die`) and dead cells that will become alive (`to_alive`). This can be done as follows.

```
def transitions(grid)
  rows = 0..grid.size - 1
  cols = 0..grid.first.size - 1
  rows.each_with_object([]) do |i, cells_to_flip|
    cols.each do |j|
      cell = [i, j]
      n = neighbors_alive(grid, cell)
      if grid[i][j] # alive
        cells_to_flip << cell unless [2, 3].include?(cell)
      else          # dead
        cells_to_flip << cell if n == 3
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
cells_to_flip = transitions(grid)
  #=> [[2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [5, 3]]
```

---

We then need to update the grid.

```
def update_grid(grid, cells_to_flip)
  cells_to_flip.each { |i, j| grid[i][j] = ! grid[i][j] }
end
```

Let's try this with a deep copy of `grid` (so we don't modify the original `grid`, which will use below in `conway(grid)`), using the values of `to_die` and `to_alive` above.

```
arr = grid.dup.map(&:dup)
update_grid(arr, cells_to_flip)
display_grid(arr)
```

We see that all live cells die and the dead cells at `[3, 2]` and `[5, 3]` are revived.

---

We may now write a method to play the game. Recall that at each iteration a live cell dies if has fewer than two or more than three live neighbors and a dead cell springs back to life if it has exactly three live neighbors.

```
def conway(grid, delay, max_iterations)
   rows = 0..grid.size - 1
   cols = 0..grid.first.size - 1
   iterations = 0
   display_grid(grid)
   sleep(delay)
   loop do
     break if iterations == max_iterations
     iterations += 1
     cells_to_flip = transitions(grid)
     break if cells_to_flip.empty?
     update_grid(grid, cells_to_flip)
     display_grid(grid)
     sleep(delay)
   end
end
```

---

Let's try it.

```
conway(grid, 2, 1_000_000)
```

This displays the grid three times, two seconds apart, and then exits as there were no further changes to be made after the last iteration.